# Automapper conditionally map properties

Tags: c#, automapper

How can I map my properties conditionally also the value is conditional.
Below is my code details:-

```
public class Team
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public Driver Driver { get; set; }
    public Driver Codriver { get; set; }
}

public class Driver
{
    public string DriverId { get; set; }
    public List<Score> Scores { get; set; }
}

public class Score
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public int Score1 { get; set; }
    public int Score2 { get; set; }
}
```

I want to move driver and codriver. If I want to update my Driver then Score1 will be updated else Score2. If I want to update it with Driver then Score1 detail will be moved else Score2. My mapping is as below:-

```
public void Move(Score sourceScore, string sourceType, Score targetScore, string targetType)
{
    Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
    {
       cfg.CreateMap<Score, Score>()
       .ForMember(dest => dest.Score1, opt =>
       {
          opt.Condition((System.Func<Score, bool>) (src => string.Equals(targetType, "Driver")));
          opt.MapFrom(src => string.Equals(sourceType, "Driver") ? src.Score1 : src.Score2);
       })
       .ForMember(dest => dest.Score2, opt =>
       {
          opt.Condition((System.Func<Score, bool>) (src => string.Equals(targetType, "CoDriver")));
          opt.MapFrom(src => string.Equals(sourceType, "Driver") ? src.Score1 : src.Score2);
       });
    });

    Mapper.Map<Score, Score>(sourceScore, targetScore);    
}
```

The mapping done above doesn't map the details correctly. Am I missing something. Can someone help me with this.

Comment: I would replace the condition and the MapFrom with a resolver. It seems more straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

You have to review your logic and explain exactly what you want to obtain. Currently your code does this:

1. If `targetType` is `"Driver"` and `sourceType` is `"Driver"`: Score1 in destination gets the value from Score1 in source.
2. If `targetType` is `"Driver"` and `sourceType` is **anything but `"Driver"`**: Score1 in destination gets the value from Score2 in source.
3. If `targetType` is `"CoDriver"` and `sourceType` is `"Driver"`: Score2 in destination gets the value from Score1 in source.
4. If `targetType` is `"CoDriver"` and `sourceType` is **anything but `"Driver"`**: Score2 in destination gets the value from Score2 in source.

If this is not what you want, please modify this rules to state it crearly. Note that when you ask a question like this you should specify clearly what is not working as expected, and ideally provide a working example and some unit tests specifying desired behaviour. Like this:

### My code:

```
internal static class MappingDrivers
{
    public static void Move(Score sourceScore, string sourceType, Score targetScore, string targetType)
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<Score, Score>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Score1, opt =>
            {
                opt.Condition(src => string.Equals(targetType, "Driver"));
                opt.MapFrom(src => string.Equals(sourceType, "Driver") ? src.Score1 : src.Score2);
            })
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Score2, opt =>
            {
                opt.Condition(src => string.Equals(targetType, "CoDriver"));
                opt.MapFrom(src => string.Equals(sourceType, "Driver") ? src.Score1 : src.Score2);
            });
        });

        Mapper.Map(sourceScore, targetScore);
    }
}
```

### Unit tests specifying desired behaviour:

<sup>NOTE: I didn't use TestCase to keep things simple</sup>

```
internal class TestMappingDrivers
{
    [Test]
    public void WhenTargetIsDriverAndSourceIsDriver_Score1GetsValueFromScore1()
    {
        int score1 = 666;
        var source = new Score
        {
            Score1 = score1,
            Score2 = 667
        };
        var destination = new Score();

        MappingDrivers.Move(source, "Driver", destination, "Driver");

        Assert.AreEqual(score1, destination.Score2);    // Intentionally failing, it should be Assert.AreEqual(score1, destination.Score1);
    }

    [Test]
    public void WhenTargetIsDriverAndSourceIsSomethingElse_Score1GetsValueFromScore2()
    {
        int score2 = 667;
        var source = new Score
        {
            Score1 = 666,
            Score2 = score2
        };
        var destination = new Score();

        MappingDrivers.Move(source, "SomethingElse", destination, "Driver");

        Assert.AreEqual(score2, destination.Score1);   // Passing
    }

    [Test]
    public void WhenTargetIsCoDriverAndSourceIsDriver_Score1GetsValueFromScore1()
    {
        int score1 = 666;
        var source = new Score
        {
            Score1 = score1,
            Score2 = 667
        };
        var destination = new Score();

        MappingDrivers.Move(source, "Driver", destination, "CoDriver");

        Assert.AreEqual(score1, destination.Score2);   // Passing
    }

    [Test]
    public void WhenTargetIsCoDriverAndSourceIsSomethingElse_Score1GetsValueFromScore2()
    {
        int score2 = 667;
        var source = new Score
        {
            Score1 = 666,
            Score2 = score2
        };
        var destination = new Score();

        MappingDrivers.Move(source, "SomethingElse", destination, "CoDriver");

        Assert.AreEqual(score2, destination.Score2);   // Passing
    }
}
```

Note also, that you should initialize your mappings just once, usually during your application startup. Here you are doing it every time the `Move` function is called. Look in [the docs](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration.html).

Finally, I would say that you are using the wrong tool for this job. AutoMapper is commonly used to map between two different classes, not from one instance of a class to other instance of the same class. You can do it, but it's "weird". I think that for what you are trying to do, a normal conditional expression (if...else) would express your intent more clearly and be less error-prone.

Comment: The explaination given for what my code does is correct. The mapping that I have written to do this via. automapper doesn't work correctly as in data is not updated at all in destination.

Comment: I don't understand why you say it it not working. I added the working code (exactly as you posted it, but inside a static class and method) and 4 unit tests that prove it works as expected.